# Akka - GC overhead limit exceeded

Tags: java, scala, akka

I am getting a:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
    at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.asReadOnlyBuffer(HeapByteBuffer.java:117)
    at akka.util.ByteString$ByteString1.asByteBuffer(ByteString.scala:153)
    at akka.util.ByteString$ByteString1C.asByteBuffer(ByteString.scala:104)
```

With this Akka code:

```
  var buffer = ByteString.apply()
  val MsgSize = 208

  protected def onMessage(rawMsg: ByteString) = {

    // Messages under the size are not processed in while loop.  This line appends them
    // to be processed when enough data is present.
    buffer ++= rawMsg

    // Process multiple messages if present.
    while (buffer.size >= MsgSize) {
      // Process each message, leaves remainder for later processing.
    }

    // To prevent the buffer from growing uncontrollably.
    // It is possible that at some point this fails to run for a long time 
    // which could cause the out of memory exception.
    if (buffer.isEmpty) buffer = ByteString.apply()
  }
```

It looks like the concatenation may be the problem.  Is this the right way to do this?

Comment: Does the buffer decrease or get emptied at some point? The loop maybe? As far as I see it from here, it is not a guarantee. Could you possibly use a more strictly defined message type, without messing around with the bytes?
I also don' see the point of the `if (buffer.isEmpty) buffer = ByteString.apply()`, even with the comment. Also, you say you process multiple messages if present. There should not be a situation where multiple messages are present in the buffer. You can process the rawMsg by itself, and when it is processed, the next one will be fetched from the mailbox.

Comment: @AleksandarStojadinovic Right on.  The buffer was not being emptied properly.

Answer (score 2):

Turns out we have to do something like this:

```
while (buffer.size >= MsgSize) {
  val (msg, rem) = buffer.splitAt(MsgSize)

  // Process msg

  // buffer is now what remains
  buffer = rem
}
```

Because reading from the buffer does not increment a position.